# Why won't the Tooltip appear correctly when i hover the mouse over the Kendosparkline?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, sparklines

I created Kendosparkline chart in a grid , I created two sparklines over each other, but when i hover the mouse over the sparkline , the tooltip won't appear correctly 
(In fact the tooltip appears but it is unreadable and messy)

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/hRJfv/2/embedded/result/)

```
      $("#sparkline").kendoSparkline({
            type: "area",

            series: [{
                name: "World",
                data: [15.7, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5, 3.5],
                field: "Rain",
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [0.7, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],
                field: "Rain",
            }],


        });
```

thank you

Comment: Hi, the fiddle doesn't seem to show any sparkline, can you review please.

Comment: But in my browser there is no problem and others have shown
Please do not use opera browser

Comment: You can also use this http://jsfiddle.net/hRJfv/8/embedded/result/

Comment: I also put a picture to be sure that right sparkline displays            https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mp20mw7izrycq2/pSAtLnYGW3/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sparkline tooltip is rendered in-place and can't overflow out of the grid cell.

This is something that we (the Kendo UI team) are looking to address in the next major release.

You can use the following style overrides as a workaround:

```
.k-sparkline .k-tooltip table {
    table-layout: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.k-sparkline .k-tooltip table td {
    border-left-width: auto;
    text-overflow: clip;
}

.k-sparkline .k-tooltip table td,
.k-sparkline .k-tooltip table th {
    border-width: 0;
}

.k-grid td {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.k-grid-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for the answer, you mentioned apply css code but got a big problem and that overflow occurs when the grid is the style I use http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/hRJfv/15/embedded/result/                https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mp20mw7izrycq2/rS4nKunGO5/sparklines.PNG    https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mp20mw7izrycq2/GU-SHLRdCL/overflow.PNG

Comment: The problem was solved
Should be written to the end of the two css                             **.k-grid td {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

#sparkline .k-grid-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
}**